# Typescript conditional types inferred by high order function

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, promise, async-await, conditional-types

I have a function that can return a sync or async result

```ts
type HookHandler<T> = (context: MyClass<T>) => boolean | Promise<boolean>;
```

and a class that takes a list of that functions

```ts
class MyClass<T> {

    constructor(private handlers: Array<HookHandler<T>>) {

    }

    public invokeHandlers() : boolean | Promise<boolean> {
        // invoke each handler and return:
        // - Promise<boolean> if exist a handler that return a Promise<T>
        // - boolean if all handlers are synchronous
    }

}
```

I was wondering if there is any chance to make typescript infer the return type of the `invokeHandlers()` based on the given handlers. Consider that all the handlers are declared at design time:

```ts
const myClassSync = new MyClass<MyType>([
   (ctx) => true,
   (ctx) => false
]);

const myClassAsync = new MyClass<MyType>([
   async (ctx) => Promise.resolve(true),
   async (ctx) => Promise.reject()
]);

const myClassMix = new MyClass<MyType>([
   async (ctx) => Promise.resolve(true),
  (ctx) => true
]);
```

Can I make the return type of `invokeHandlers()` dependent of the types of the current given hanlders without an explicit casting? So for example

```ts
// all handlers are sync, infer boolean
const allHandlersAreOk: boolean = myClassSync.invokeHandlers()

// all handlers are async, infer Promise<boolean>
const allAsyncHandlersAreOk: Promise<boolean> = await myClassAsync.invokeHandlers()

// at least one handler is async, infer Promise<boolean>
const allMixedHandlersAreOk: Promise<boolean> = await myClassMix.invokeHandlers()
```

I can obviously return a simple `Promise<boolean>`, but I would loose the possibility to call the `invokeHandlers()` in synchronous contexts, and it want to avoid that.

Any suggestions or other design choice to face the problem? Thank you!

Comment: I might have a solution for you but your code has no structural dependence of the `T` parameter, so I plan to exclude it.

Comment: The generic type is copy-pasted from the real code, this is just a simplification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach it:

Come up with separate types for each possible hook handler:

```
type SyncHookHandler = (context: MyClass<any>) => boolean;
type AsyncHookHandler = (context: MyClass<any>) => Promise<boolean>;
type HookHandler = AsyncHookHandler | SyncHookHandler;
```

And then make `MyClass` depend on the type `HH` of `HookHandler` you use.  The return type of `invokeHandlers` can be a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) which evaluates to `boolean` if `HH` is `SyncHookHandler`, and `Promise<boolean>` if `HH` is `AsyncHookHandler` or `AsyncHookHandler | SyncHookHandler`:

```
class MyClass<HH extends HookHandler> {

  constructor(private handlers: Array<HH>) { }

  public invokeHandlers(): Promise<boolean> extends ReturnType<HH> ? 
    Promise<boolean> : boolean;
  public invokeHandlers(): boolean | Promise<boolean> {

    const rets = this.handlers.map(h => h(this));

    const firstPromise = rets.find(r => typeof r !== 'boolean');
    if (firstPromise) {
      return firstPromise; // ‍ what do you want to return here
    }
    // must be all booleans
    const allBooleanRets = rets as boolean[];
    return allBooleanRets.every(b => b);  // ‍ what do you want to return here 
  }
}
```

I just did some silly implementation inside `invokeHandlers()` to give an idea of what you'd be doing there.  Now you can see that your code behaves as expected

```
const myClassSync = new MyClass([
  (ctx) => true,
  (ctx) => false
]);
// all handlers are sync, infer boolean
const allHandlersAreOk: boolean = myClassSync.invokeHandlers()

const myClassAsync = new MyClass([
  async (ctx) => Promise.resolve(true),
  async (ctx) => Promise.reject()
]);
// all handlers are async, infer Promise<boolean>
// note you do not "await" it, since you want a Promise
const allAsyncHandlersAreOk: Promise<boolean> = myClassAsync.invokeHandlers()

const myClassMix = new MyClass([
  async (ctx) => Promise.resolve(true),
  (ctx) => true
]);
// at least one handler is async, infer Promise<boolean>
// note you do not "await" it, since you want a Promise
const allMixedHandlersAreOk: Promise<boolean> = myClassMix.invokeHandlers()
```

Does that work for you?

Please note that since the example code had no structural dependence on the generic parameter `T`, I've [removed it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--).  If you need it you can add it back in the appropriate places, but I'm assuming the question is more about detect-sync-if-you-can and less about some generic type.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 1):

you could use overloads if you have a way to differentiate between your handlers or identify them in some way at runtime

```
function handler(x: number): string;
function handler(y: string): number;
function handler(arg) {
    if (typeof arg === 'number') {
        return `${arg}`
    } else {
        return parseInt(arg);
    }
}

const inferred = handler(1); // <-- typescript correctly infers string
const alsoInferred = handler('1'); // <-- typescript correctly infers number
```

So if you could write something like:

```
function handler(context: AsyncHandler): Promise<boolean>;
function handler(context: MixedHandlers): Promise<boolean>;
function handler(context: SyncHandlers): boolean:
function handler(context){
  // your implementation, maybe instanceof if each type has a class representation
}
```

TypeScript could correctly infer the return type. I'm not sure if this is possible based on your code structure but I thought I would share. Read more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html), specifically the section on overloads

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

That some of them might return promises is a fact. That's the most TypeScript *can* know.

If they are or not all returning promises can only be determined at run time.

So the answer is no, TypeScript can't infer something that is only inferable at run time.

Comment: Makes sense. Could be a solution for you to split the `invokeHandlers()` in two functions, one that returns a `boolean` and the other returning a `Promise<boolean>`?

Comment: Yes, but then the one that can only return `boolean` will have to be typed in such a way that its parameters can never be promises, forcing you (as the programmer) to use the correct one from the start. And this would basically remove the advantage of being able to mix async and sync handlers. OR you could make the check at runtime instead of compile time, but then you loose the advantages of TypeScript.

Comment: Yes, that was the point. Currently I'm ignoring async handlers if the caller uses the sync version of the `invokeHandlers()`, but I was looking for a more clean solution